# Disable Google Chrome Context Menu

Tags: windows, google-chrome, right-click, kiosk

Ok, we are setting up a computer lab for students. They will be only using one website, and they like to break the computers, go to game sites, download music, etc, every chance possible. We are already setting up Chrome in kiosk mode. However, is there a way to disable the context menu? Sadly, using something such as autohotkey will not work because we're replacing the shell with the kiosk mode browser. So, is there any registry tweak, or something similar, to just disable right click?

Comment: Do you have any single-button mice from a mac laying around?

Comment: Your possible solutions change depending on the version of Windows you are using.  Windows 8.1 will have a kiosk mode.  There is also kiosk based software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As users [have indicated here](https://superuser.com/questions/262995/how-to-disable-right-click-in-windows-xp-windows-7), there doesn't seem to be a universal way to disable the right click context menu.

However, you can still accomplish what you want using autohotkey. Just create a script that disables the right click and then launch your desired application, [chrome in this case](http://windows7themes.net/google-chrome-exe-location.html). Then just [compile the script to an EXE](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) and you can launch this instead of the explorer shell, for example:

```
#NoTrayIcon
RButton::Return
Run , C:\<pathtochrome>\chrome.exe --incognito www.mykioskwebsite.com
```

Comment: Brilliant idea, working on it now

Comment: @TechHeadDJ Don't forgot a green check mark if the answer qualifies. Thanks! Good luck!

Comment: Forgot about that. Been a while since I've turned to the stack world for aid. Just working on the finesse of the script to make it work... getting lockup's on the launch.

Comment: With `-kiosk` switch on, it works wonderfully. Using this, I can also disable a ton of other things! Sadly, however, no ctrl+alt+del, but I can do that with a group policy change. The students are in for a surprise. That works great!